# in In android: How can I perform tasks while out of focus and then safely return to original activity and continue there?

Tags: android, service, focus

I have an application that needs to continue to perform certain tasks while the application is out of focus, and would like a reliable way to return to the original activity and continue when focus is regained.I want a neat structure so that it works regardless of whether the os shuts down my activites.

My current idea is to start a service when on pause is called, let the service continue the work the activity did while the activity was in focus and kill the activity. When the user returns to the application, I would like to relaunch the activity, let it take over everything and kill the service. The problem with that is that I can't find a way for the service to know when the aplication regains focus  so it can relaunch the activity. How can I do this?

Also, is this a good structure for what I want to do, or is there a better way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class which extends `Application`. Whenever any app starts, this class is launched before any activity. So, when you're inside this class's `onCreate()` , it means the app has the focus now. And, you can also get to know whether the app was killed or user had finished it systematically through your app only, by setting some variable in your `shared preferences`.

Comment: Yes sure. Revert back and let us all know.

Comment: I've been looking around some more, and this isn't what I was looking for. Application's onCreate is only called when the application is first started. I need some sort of onResume, which is always called when focus is regained.